# Why does it take so long for my USB speakers to be recognized by pulseaudio?

Tags: 11.10, usb, pulseaudio

I have an XBMCBuntu installation (based on Ubuntu 11.10), meaning that I don't have a graphical desktop environment installed.

I've connected a set of USB speakers, and for about a minute or two, running `pacmd list-sinks` yields only one sink:  my laptop's onboard sound card.

After about 3 minutes, running the same command yields both the original sound card and the USB speakers, at which point I can run `pacmd set-default-sink alsa_output.usb-1130_USB_AUDIO-00-AUDIO.analog-stereo` and play sound out of the peripheral speakers.

Unfortunately, the changes brought forth by the `pacmd set-default-sink` command aren't persistent across reboots.  I suspect that this is because pulseaudio falls back on the onboard sound card when it can't detect the USB speakers for those first three minutes.  Of course, I'm not *really* sure that this is the case, but it begs the following questions:

1. Why does it take so long to detect the speakers;  Is there anything I can do to speed things up?
2. Is there a way of making these changes persistent other than scheduling a cronjob to run `pacmd set-default-sink alsa_output.usb-1130_USB_AUDIO-00-AUDIO.analog-stereo` after a few minutes of uptime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have no solution for the long timeout your system needs to recognize an external USB sound device but there is a way to connect the Pulse Audio output sink with this device as soon as it was available (as loading a default sink in your `default.pa` is not possible when the device is not ready by the time the sound server is started).

Pulseaudio **module-switch-on-connect** enables automatic switching of an audio device on connection. To test if this works we may issue the following commmand in a terminal:

```
pacmd load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

On success we may add the following line to our `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

```
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

to always load this module per default.

Now the Pulseaudio output sink should be switched to any newly connected sink, in your case this would be your USB audio device.

Comment: This is certainly an acceptable solution!  Just a quick question, however.  Running the `pacmd load-module module-switch-on-connect` command yields an output of `Welcome to PulseAudio!  use "help" for usage information`.  I got this same output when running the `set-default-sink` command, but it **did** work.  May I assume that this command worked as well?

Comment: See with `pacmd list-modules` if it's there. It should be, otherwise you would have seen an error.